# Zip files and folders from different project and import in another project

Tags: python, import, zip, tar

I have a python projects structure in the following way

```
common_project
|---folder
|   |--- file1.py
|   |--- file2.py
|   |--- file3.py


project
|---src
|----|---main_file.py
```

I need to access the functions of file1.py and file2.py in main_file.py. How can I zip the files of common folder so that I can import as

```
from common.file1 import func1
```

I tried to zip the folder as `zip -r common_files.zip common_project/folder/` . But the file is zipping as :

```
adding: common_project/folder/file1.py (stored 0%)
adding: common_project/folder/file2.py
```

But I need to import as  `from common import file1.py`
Any help would be appreciatable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to do imports as indicated, the zip file must be structured accordingly:

```
common
|--- file1.py
|--- file2.py
|--- file3.py
```

I don't know if you can achieve this with `zip` directly. I used a symbolic link as a workaround:

```
$ ln -s common_project/folder common
$ zip -r common_files.zip common
  adding: common/ (stored 0%)
  adding: common/file1.py (deflated 10%)
  adding: common/file3.py (deflated 10%)
  adding: common/file2.py (deflated 10%)
$ rm common
$ unzip -l common_files.zip 
Archive:  common_files.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2021-02-22 13:46   common/
       41  2021-02-22 13:50   common/file1.py
       41  2021-02-22 13:50   common/file3.py
       41  2021-02-22 13:50   common/file2.py
---------                     -------
      123                     4 files
```

One more thing you need to do is add the zip file to Python's import search path:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/absolute/path/to/common_files.zip python
```

and then the imports should work:

```
>>> from common.file1 import func1
>>> func1()
This is func1
>>> from common import file2
>>> file2.func2()
This is func2
```